# write an for loop function in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would like to write a simple function that loops through a vector and adds one to each value. How should I go about it?

```
x<-1:10
x_plus_one<-function(i){
  for (i in x)
    i+1}
```

This function does not return anything.

What is expected should be sthg like below:

```
> x1<-x+1
> x1
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: `x_plus_one <- function(x) { for(i in seq_along(x)) x[i] <- x[i] + 1; return(x) }`

Comment: If this is a class assignment and you are not explicitly asked to code a `for` loop, a one-liner will do it: `x_plus_one <- function(x) {x+1}`

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Allan Cameron

```
func <- function(x) 
{ for(i in seq_along(x)) 
    x[i] <- x[i] + 1; 
return(x)
}
x<-(5:10)
> func(x)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11
```